# How to detect - mouse right or left key is primary?

Tags: java, mouse

How to detect - mouse right or left key is primary using java?

Comment: Have you tried anything? My first guess would be that `BUTTON1` on the `MouseEvent` would always be the primary button.

Comment: yes Button1 always be the primary, but question. It will be pressed left or right button? If it "left button" I wont use it as Button1 but if it "right button" i will be use it as Button2

Comment: define: "a primary" button, so you get a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect there's no way to do this without getting into OS specifics, since it's an OS abstraction.

See also: [How do I detect mouse configuration?](http://www.javakb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/java-programmer/45997/How-do-I-detect-mouse-configuration)